# Retrieve Data from SQL with input from table

Tags: sql, vba, datatable

I have a table in excel, with range : Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d4:d215"). These data are similar to PS.WELL in the server.

From that table, I want to retrieve data using this code (other SQL requisite has been loaded, this is the main code only):

```
strquery = "SELECT PS.WELL, PS.TYPE, PS.TOPSND " & _
    "FROM ISYS.PS PS " & _
    "WHERE PS.WELL = '" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D215") "' AND (PS.TYPE = 'O' OR PS.TYPE = 'O_' OR PS.TYPE = 'GOW') " & _
    "ORDER BY PS.WELL"
```

Unfortunately it didn't work. Can anyone help me how to write the code especially in the 'where' section?

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through each item in the range and concatenate the results to a string variable so the contents look like this

```
'val1','val2','val3'
```

Then you have to adjust your query code to use the IN operator instead of equals operator. Let's say the string is concatenated to a variable called myrange.

```
"WHERE PS.WELL IN (" & myrange & ") AND ...
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of the concatenate ? Or would you like to type one for me from above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The key is to make 2 function of SQL:

1. to read and write each input
2. to count number of output per input (an input can have 0, 1, or more output).

then, just call using procedure